# Import project in android studio 1.0

Tags: android, ide

When I import Google play service to android studio that's open a new window whereas I don't want it and when select "this window" in opening time, it close my project. I want import multiple project in same window like eclipse.(I watched this video [clipconver.cc link](http://www.clipconverter.cc/download/EL2EHOpg/104842673/))

How I can use Google play service in my project in android studio 1.0?

Answer (score 0):

If you want add dependence, I recommend using `Gradle`.
You can use `gradle` in android studio.

find out `build.gradle` in your project then add google play service at dependencies like this.

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:+'

//Example
dependencies {
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:+'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:+'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:+'}
```

Or You can add other project in your project similar as Eclipse.

```
File -> Import Module
```

Comment: I have two build.gradle which of them? project or module.

Comment: I added but I cant run my app, because gradle has error

Comment: What error? Maybe you can see the reason of the error or log.

Comment: Gradle project sync failed. basic functionality(e.g editing, debugging) will not work properly!

Comment: have you video about work on google maps in android studio 1.0? (if (true){give link address;}else{nothing;})